# Conditionally passing a modified copy instead of const original becomes ugly

Tags: c++

I have a situation like the following in my code:

```
#include <memory>

struct X
{
    int i;
};


std::shared_ptr<const X> getProtoX();

void modifyX(X&);

void consumeX(const X&);


void suboptimal(bool condition)
{
    std::shared_ptr<const X> x = getProtoX();

    X copy(*x);
    if (condition)
        modifyX(copy);

    consumeX(copy);
}
```

Take note that `getProtoX()` returns a pointer-to-const!

We get a `const` object from somewhere and want to either pass it on without modification or pass on a modified copy. `consumeX` does not care whether it receives the original or a modified copy, just that the contained value is what it should be. The above code always copies an `X`, even if `condition` is false and no copy is required.

I would like to avoid this needless copy when `condition == false`, but none of the ways I can think of please me: https://godbolt.org/z/YGLVxT

See, if `getProtoX()` returned a `std::shared_ptr<X>`, the task would be easy:

```
std::shared_ptr<X> x = getProtoX();

if (condition)
{
    x = std::make_shared<X>(*x);
    modifyX(*x);
}

consumeX(*x);
```

**This is the control flow that I want to express in the code.** But as soon as we add const-correctness, we incur either overhead or have to totally obscure the intent due to a mix of `const`, scope, and lifetime management constraints.

I feel like there should be a clean way to do this in the const-correct case without syntactic acrobatics like immediately-invoked-lambdas or moving the operation into a separate function, but I can't find it. Please note that there should be only one `consumeX` call and it should stay at function scope (encoding this in the example code would make a bit of a mess and prompt more workarounds that are not what I care about here).

Comment: Really `getProtoX` should be changed.  If it is returning a `const`, then you need to copy to get a modifiable object.

Comment: @NathanOliver I want to avoid the needless copy if (and only if) `condition` is false. I will attempt to make this clearer.

Comment: I assume constructing an `X` is costly too? (so you want to conditionally create/delete it on condition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::shared_ptr<const X> x = getProtoX();

if (condition)
{
    std::shared_ptr<X> y = std::make_shared<X>(*x);
    modifyX(*y);
    x = std::move(y);
}

consumeX(*x);
```

Comment: Good answer, I somehow missed this option. I also like how the `std::move` actually improves clarity.

Comment: I don't think the move improves clarity, but it does avoid a small amount of refcounting antics that you don't need

Answer (score 1):

While [the existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57276045) is optimal when `condition` is false, it allocates an `X` object on the heap when `condition` is true. To allocate `X` on the stack:

Assume constructing an `X` object is not expensive, you can do the following:

```
std::shared_ptr<const X> x = getProtoX();

X modified;
if (condition)
{
    modified = *x;
    modifyX(modified);
}

X const& desired = condition ? modified : *x;

consumeX(desired);
```

This has the disadvantage of constructing a new `X` object regardless of `condition`.

It's possible to allocate memory on stack without construction:

```
std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(X), alignof(X)> modified_mem;
X* modified;
if (condition)
{
    modified = new(&modified_mem) X(*x);
    modifyX(*modified);
}

X const& desired = condition ? *modified : *x;

consumeX(desired);

if (condition) modified->~X();
```

but it's pretty complex.